# What did Richard Dedekind mean exactly by his statement about generality?

Tags: logic, foundations, philosophy

> But—and in this mathematics is distinguished from other sciences—these
> extensions of definitions no longer allow scope for arbitrariness; on
> the contrary, they follow with compelling necessity from the earlier
> restricted definitions, provided one applies the following principle:
> Laws which emerge from the initial definitions and which are
> characteristic for the concepts that they designate are to be
> considered as *of general validity*. Then these laws conversely become
> the source of the generalized definitions if one asks: How must the
> general definition be conceived in order that the discovered
> characteristic laws be always satisfied?—It is now my intention to
> illustrate this principle of induction with several examples.

—Richard Dedekind, “On the Introduction of New Functions,” 1854, §6 (in *From Kant to Hilbert: A Source Book in the Foundations of Mathematics,* edited by William B. Ewald, 1996, p. 757)

My question is about the meaning of the sentence: "which are characteristic for the concepts that they designate".

How do I know if something is characteristic of a concept it demonstrates?

He gives an example about extending distributivity over multiplication to integers here:

> We already have a definite example in multiplication. This operation
> arose from the requirement that a multiply-repeated performance of an
> operation of the next lower rank [Ordnung] — namely the addition of a
> fixed positive or negative addend (the so-called multiplicand) — be
> collected together into a single act. The multiplier — that is, the
> number which states how often the addition of the multiplicand is to
> be thought of as repeated — is therefore at the outset necessarily a
> positive integer; a negative multiplier would, under this first
> definition of multiplication, make absolutely no sense. So, admit
> negative multipliers as well, and thereby to liberate the operation
> from the initial constraint; but such a definition involves *a priori*
> complete arbitrariness, and it would only later be decided whether
> then this arbitrarily chosen definition would bring any real use to
> arithmetic; and even if the definition succeeded, one could only call
> it a lucky guess, a happy coincidence — the sort of thing a scientific
> method ought to avoid. So let us instead apply our general principle.
> We must investigate which laws govern the product if the multiplier
> undergoes in succession the same general alterations which led to the
> creation of the sequence of negative integers out of the sequence of
> positive integers. For this it suffices if we determine the alteration
> which the product undergoes if one makes the simplest numerical
> operation with the multiplier, namely, allowing it to go over into the
> next-following number. By successive repetition of this operation we
> obtain the familiar addition theorem for the multiplier: in order to
> multiply a number by a sum, one multiplies it by each summand and then
> adds these partial products together. From this theorem a subtraction
> theorem immediately follows for the case where the minuend is greater
> than the subtrahend. If one now declares this law to be valid in
> general (that is, to hold also when the difference which the
> multiplier represents is negative) then one obtains the definition of
> multiplication with negative multipliers; and it is then of course no
> accident that the general law which multiplication obeys is exactly
> the same for both cases.

—§8, *ibid*. pp. 757-758.

Comment: Already asked [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/17258/what-does-dedekind-mean-by-laws-characteristic-for-the-concepts)

Comment: Having said that, the statement expresses a sort of ["structuralism"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dedekind-foundations/#LogStr): "What, then, are the natural numbers? They are those mathematical objects whose properties are determined by all arithmetic truths; we “abstract away” from everything else in terms of a logical procedure. Moreover, this procedure can be spelled out, precisely and consistently, in terms of “structural abstraction principles”."

Comment: <<My question is about the meaning of the sentence: "[laws] which are characteristic for the concepts that they designate".>>  It is another way to say that the concept is *defined by* those laws.